# While using bulk_create() -> error = "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: django

In this file, I am trying to post user information, either one or many using bulk_create()

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_user(request):
    print("INSIDE")
    print(request.data)
    if len(request.data) == 1:
        user_data = UserInfoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if user_data.is_valid():
            user_data.save()
        return Response(user_data.data)
    else:
        UserData.objects.bulk_create(request.data, batch_size=1000)
```

The request which I send is

```
[{"name":"George","gpa":2}, {"name":"Dev","gpa":4}, {"name":"Bianca","gpa":3.2}]
```

**serializer.py**

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gpa = models.IntegerField()
    age = models.ForeignKey('master.sometable', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.DateField()
```

When I send a request with one dictionary, data gets uploaded. But not with multiple

edit: added serializer, models and changed the error

Comment: `bulk_create` does not work like that, please add your `serializer` to the question

Comment: added it @MohamedHamza